# Expected Value of E(x) with two cdf's $F(x)\leq G(x)$

Tags: expectation

> A random variable **X** is distributed in **[0, 1]**. 
>       Mr. Fox believes that
>   **X** follows a distribution with cumulative density function (cdf) $F : [0, 1]\rightarrow [0, 1]$ and Mr. Goat believes that **X** follows a
>   distribution with cdf $G : [0, 1] \rightarrow  [0, 1]$. Assume **F**
>   and **G** are differentiable, $F\neq G$ and $F(x) \leq G(x)$ for all
>   $x\in   [0, 1]$ . Let $E_{F} [X]$ and $E_{G}[X]$ be the expected
>   values of **X** for Mr. Fox and Mr. Goat respectively. Which of the
>   following is true?
>
> (a)$E_{F}[X] \leq E_{G}[X]$
>
> (b) $E_{F}[X] \geq E_{G}[X]$
>
> (c) $E_{F}[X] = E_{G}[X]$
>
> (d) None of the above.

The solution to this is: http://discussion-forum.2150183.n2.nabble.com/file/n7588025/sol.png

Which i find extremely difficult. Can someone provide me with an easier and more understandable possible solution? Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution looks difficult because you need to first derive a key identity: for any nonnegative random variable $X$, the following holds:

$$E[X]=\int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx.$$

That's the first part of the derivation. Once you have this the rest will follow.

Comment: Thankyou, but isn't there an intuitive way to think about this question?

Comment: Intuitively, since $X$ is non-negative, if $F\leq G$ this means that  $X_F$ will take on higher values with higher probability than $X_G$, whereas $X_G$ will take on lower values with higher probability.